# IF function with two logical tests

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help with creating a formula with two logical tests. I got the first one but can't figure out how to include the second logical test.

[image]

My formula currently: If column E=S, I want Annual Salary to be divided by total days in a year and times number of days in a month, if cell E=H I want annual salary to be multiplied by percentage in column U. This is an allocation of total wages by month. But also if Column N=6% I need to add 6% increase to this allocation. And that's where I am stuck.

Comment: This question is very hard to understand, please specify what you want more clearly.

Comment: please update/edit you're question, don't just write it in the comments.

Comment: " But also if Column N=6% I need to add 6% increase " do you mean column M=6%? ( I didn't see a % value in column N...)

Comment: @kate, Add proper screen shot since values in AH4 & U 40 are out of the screen!!

Answer (score 0):

```
=(if(e6=s6,<AnnualSalary/totalDaysInYear*NumberofDaysinMonth>,if(e6=H6,<AnnualSalary*H6>,"notEqualtoEitherS or H column"))*(if(M6="6%",1.06,1)
```

Replace the <> with formula that you defined.